# Merge the output of two sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle11g, merge, cursor

I've two functions in oracle 11g which return a sys_refcursos.
The first in this

```
create or replace FUNCTION num_gettoni
    (cf_parlamentare IN parlamentari.cf %TYPE DEFAULT 'MRTMRZ'
      --, num_legislatura in legislature.id%TYPE
    ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    pippo legislature.id%type;
  BEGIN

    OPEN my_cursor FOR

    select
      leg, 
      ct as gettoni
    from( 
       SELECT
         l.id AS leg,
         COUNT(*) - lead(COUNT(*), 1, 0) over (order by l.datainizio) AS ct
       FROM
         legislature l,
         partecipazioni i,
         parlamentari p
       WHERE 
         i.sedute_data >= l.datainizio 
         AND p.cf = i.parlamentare 
         AND p.cf = cf_parlamentare

       group by l.datainizio, l.id
    )

    where ct > 0
    order by ct desc;

    /*open my_cursor;
    loop
    pippo := my_cursor.leg;
    END LOOP;

    end loop;*/

    RETURN my_cursor;
  END num_gettoni;
```

An example of the output of the first funzion is

```
select num_gettoni('MRTMRZ') from dual;

NUM_GETTONI('MRTMRZ') 
--------------------- 
LEG                    GETTONI                 
---------------------- ----------------------  
17                     3                       
18                     2
```

The second function is similar and the output of second function is

```
select num_interrogazioni('MRTMRZ') from dual;

NUM_INTERROGAZIONI('MRTMRZ') 
-------------------------------------- 
LEG                    INTERROGAZIONI          
---------------------- ----------------------  
18                     1
```

Is possible to call these functions through a procedure and have a result similar at the following?

```
NUM_INTERROGAZIONI('MRTMRZ') 
    -------------------------------------- 
    LEG                    GETTONI                 INTERROGAZIONI 
    ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------  
    17                     3                       
    18                     2                       1
```

Comment: Not easily. Who or what is going to consume the combined results? And are these functions standalone or in a package?

Comment: The unique task of this procedure is call these functions for display the results.
These functions, now, are standalone

Comment: If for you are more simple, you can suppose that the functions are in a package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple built-in mechanism to merge ref cursors; they are essentially pointers to result sets and they can't be treated as tables so they can't be joined, which is essentially what you're trying to achieve here.

If you just want to display the combined results you could use a PL/SQL collection to store the results from the first ref cursor, and then update/add to it with the results of the second, based on `leg` being the common 'key' value:

```
declare
  -- for the collection
  type t_rec is record (leg number, gettoni number, interrogazioni number);
  type t_tab is table of t_rec index by pls_integer;
  l_tab t_tab;
  -- for the cursors returned by the functions
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  -- for the individual columns from the cursors
  l_leg number;
  l_gettoni number;
  l_interrogazioni number;
begin
  l_cursor := num_gettoni('MRTMRZ');
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_leg, l_gettoni;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;
    l_tab(l_leg).leg := l_leg;
    l_tab(l_leg).gettoni := l_gettoni;
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;

  l_cursor := num_interrogazioni('MRTMRZ');
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_leg, l_interrogazioni;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;
    l_tab(l_leg).leg := l_leg;
    l_tab(l_leg).interrogazioni := l_interrogazioni;
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;

  for i in l_tab.first..l_tab.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).leg ||','|| l_tab(i).gettoni ||','|| l_tab(i).interrogazioni);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

which with dummy functions that return the results you showed, gets:

```
17,3,
18,2,1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The two cursor loop are essentially the same. Call the relevant function and loop over the results, setting values in the index-by collection element for the columns that cursor has; where in both cases the index is the `leg` value.

The first loop populates the `leg` and `gettoni` values for the record elements at indexes 17 and 18. The second only sees a result for 18 and sets the `interrogazioni` for that element. If that also had a different `leg`, say 19, then it would also populate an element with that index with both the `leg` and `interrogazioni` values. (So, essentially, it's roughly equivalent to a full outer join...)

But relying on `dbms_output` for output isn't ideal as you don't control whether the client is using that, and it's harder to format and consume. It would probably be more useful to get the result back as either a table collection you could use in a query, or possibly as a new ref cursor.

You can use a package to define the collection types, with a function that uses the mechanism above put pipes the results out as a table collection, and a second function that generates a ref cursor from that piped table:

```
create or replace package p42 as
  type t_rec is record (leg number, gettoni number, interrogazioni number);
  type t_tab is table of t_rec;

  -- function for pipelined table collection
  function num_combo_tab (p_param varchar2) return t_tab pipelined;
  -- function for ref cursor
  function num_combo_cur (p_param varchar2) return sys_refcursor;
end p42;
/
```

```
create or replace package body p42 as
  -- function for pipelined table collection
  function num_combo_tab (p_param varchar2) return t_tab pipelined is
    type t_tmp_tab is table of t_rec index by pls_integer;
    l_tab t_tmp_tab;
    l_leg number;
    l_gettoni number;
    l_interrogazioni number;
    l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  begin
    l_cursor := num_gettoni(p_param);
    loop
      fetch l_cursor into l_leg, l_gettoni;
      exit when l_cursor%notfound;
      l_tab(l_leg).leg := l_leg;
      l_tab(l_leg).gettoni := l_gettoni;
    end loop;
    close l_cursor;

    l_cursor := num_interrogazioni(p_param);
    loop
      fetch l_cursor into l_leg, l_interrogazioni;
      exit when l_cursor%notfound;
      l_tab(l_leg).leg := l_leg;
      l_tab(l_leg).interrogazioni := l_interrogazioni;
    end loop;
    close l_cursor;

    for i in l_tab.first..l_tab.last loop
      pipe row (l_tab(i));
    end loop;
  end num_combo_tab;

  -- function for ref cursor
  function num_combo_cur (p_param varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
    l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open l_cursor for
      select * from table(num_combo_tab(p_param));
    return l_cursor;
  end num_combo_cur;
end p42;
/
```

Here `num_combo_tab` is basically the anonymous block above, but it pipes the record type instead of using `dbms_output`. And then `num_combo_cur` just opens a ref cursor for that result.

So then you can do:

```
select p42.num_combo_cur('MRTMRZ') from dual;

P42.NUM_COMBO_CUR('M
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

       LEG    GETTONI INTERROGAZIONI
---------- ---------- --------------
        17          3               
        18          2              1
```

or just use the table version directly:

```
select * from table(p42.num_combo_tab('MRTMRZ'));

       LEG    GETTONI INTERROGAZIONI
---------- ---------- --------------
        17          3               
        18          2              1
```

You could also do this with schema-level object and table types and a schema-level function if you prefer:

```
create type t_obj as object (leg number, gettoni number, interrogazioni number)
/
create type t_tab is table of t_obj
/

create or replace function num_combo_tab (p_param varchar2)
return t_tab pipelined as
  type t_tmp_tab is table of t_obj index by pls_integer;
  l_tab t_tmp_tab;
  l_leg number;
  l_gettoni number;
  l_interrogazioni number;
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
  l_cursor := num_gettoni(p_param);
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_leg, l_gettoni;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;
    l_tab(l_leg) := new t_obj(l_leg, l_gettoni, null);
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;

  l_cursor := num_interrogazioni(p_param);
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_leg, l_interrogazioni;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;
    if l_tab.exists(l_leg) then
      l_tab(l_leg).interrogazioni := l_interrogazioni;
    else
      l_tab(l_leg) := new t_obj(l_leg, null, l_interrogazioni);
    end if;
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;

  for i in l_tab.first..l_tab.last loop
    pipe row (l_tab(i));
  end loop;
end num_combo_tab;
/
```

then you can call that as:

```
select * from table(num_combo_tab('MRTMRZ'));

       LEG    GETTONI INTERROGAZIONI
---------- ---------- --------------
        17          3               
        18          2              1
```

But it would probably be more sensible to have this, and probably your original functions too, in a package anyway.

---

In all the above, obviously, use your own data types and `%type` when you can, I don't have your tables so I've used e.g. `p_param varchar` instead of the way your existing functions declare their parameters.